# Can I not await for async Task without making it async void?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

When using async Task method it is required to place await before method. I need code to be executed in non UI blocking manner and don't want to await. My only idea is to use:

```
private void TaskFactory()
{ 
    CancellationTokenSource token_TaskFactory = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ParallelOptions parOpts = new ParallelOptions();
    parOpts.CancellationToken = token_TaskFactory.Token;
    parOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    TaskCreationOptions atp = new TaskCreationOptions();     
    atp = TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness;
    Task TaskFactory = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
       if (!token_TaskFactory.IsCancellationRequested)     
       {
         Thread.Sleep(5000);
       }
       else
       {

       }
    }, token_TaskFactory.Token, atp, TaskScheduler.Default); 
}
```

Comment: If you want fire+forget, then, **and only then**, `async void` is fine. You forgot to put the `async` modifier though.

Comment: Where I forgot to put async modifier? In void TaskFactory()
I don't want async to not use await then. Method doesn't block UI.

Comment: You have to put `async` in the method declaration, and you have to use `await` in the method, but you will not need to `await` the method itself.

Comment: When I don't await the method itself I get warning: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call. I wanted to prevent this type of warning. Unless I should not worry when want to use fire and forget method.

Comment: Ye, that's normal for fire+forget.

Comment: "you will not need to await the method itself" I would mark this as answer. Thank you for your effort Soner.

Answer (score 8):

> When using async Task method it is required to place await before method.

The correct way to handle this is to `await` the method, and make the calling method `async Task` or `async Task<TResult>`. This will have a cascading effect as `async` travels up through your code.

In a UI application, you will usually end up at an event handler, which *cannot* be `async Task`, and at that point you can make the event handler `async void`.

If you cheat this process by making a regular method `async void`, you cause other problems, particularly around error handling and composability (i.e. unit testing). See [my MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) or [one of the many talks](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only) about why `async void` should be avoided.

> I need code to be executed in non UI blocking manner and don't want to await.

Why don't you "want" to use `await`? You have asynchronous code that you need to run in a non-blocking fashion, and that's *exactly what `await` does!*

Comment: I don't want to use await because need to execute a few async methods parallelly without waiting one for other. Your MSDN article is priceless. Thanks Stephen.

Comment: In that case, you just start the tasks like `Task first = Task.Run(...); Task second = Task.Run(...);` and then `await` them all at once like `await Task.WhenAll(first, second);`

Comment: What if you do not care if it blocks for a bit but the only method available to you is async ?  It seems that would be the perfect scenario where you would call the async method without await.

Comment: @BillGreer: I'm not understanding your question. If the method is async, it (generally) won't block. Not using await is a kind of "fire and forget", where you don't care *when* the method completes, what the *result* is, or whether it threw an *exception*. All three of those concerns taken together are almost never true; your code usually cares about at least one of them.