# async: return task or await first in asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have a small question with async/await on webapi. Is there a difference between these two usages and which one is considered the correct one? After reading [SimilarQuestion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886992/at-the-end-of-an-async-method-should-i-return-or-await) I guess Variant 1 is better because of less overhead but I need to be sure, therefore I ask again;)

Variant 1:

```
public Task<string> Get(){
    return Bar();
}
```

variant 2:

```
public async Task<string> Get(){
    return await Bar();
}
```

Methods:

```
public async Task<string> Foo(){
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "Done";
}

public Task Bar(){
    return Foo();
}
```

Thanks for hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variant 2 is not possible because you can not do**

```
public async Task<string> Get(){
    return await Bar();
}

public Task Bar(){
    return Foo();
}
```

`await` only works for `async`  and `Task Bar()` is not `async`... its just `Task`.

Look at [Can I not await for async Task without making it async void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739676/can-i-not-await-for-async-task-without-making-it-async-void) 
It says

> The correct way to handle this is to await the method, and make the
>   calling method async Task. This will have a
>   cascading effect as async travels up through your code.

Having said that, **you are left with variant 1.** This is a good option for most cases. If you feel async await will have a negative impact on performance, you are probably making the wrong methods async. But again, you need to calibrate that. There cant be a common answer for this that address all methods.

Also see :

1. [the-overhead-of-asyncawait-in-net-4.5](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-overhead-of-asyncawait-in-net-4.5/)
2. [Behind the .NET 4.5 Async Scene: The performance impact of Asynchronous programming in C#](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2014/10/09/behind-net-4-5-async-scene-performance-impact-asynchronous-programming-c/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Should have testet it before i ask. But now i have the following question: is there a difference between those variants: async Task<string> Get(){return await Foo();} or Task<string> Get(){return Foo();}?

Comment: Yes. async adds a performance overhead. But why would you use a Task without async ?

Comment: okay, perfect. it is not production code I just try to understand how it works.  thank you!

Comment: If you have used async for the top method, it's safe to use it in all subsequent child methods as the async overheard will remain same.

Comment: Ok. And for asp.net WebAPI it makes no difference if i declare a Method as "async Task<string> Get()" and await TaskX inside of Get or if i declare it as "Task<string> Get()" and return the TaskX directly, right?

Comment: that's correct. Most of the overhead is added by the first async. That's why you should chain it until you reach the last primitive async method.